# Selenium C# Find Element with class and text

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xunit

im very new to testing and have no training in automated tests so please bare with me if i say stupid things but ill try the best i can.

Bascially i am trying to assert that a specific employee in the employee list has the status of 'leaver'.

This is what i have tried (and other variations with the different classes)

```
Assert.Equal("image-tile__badge background-color--status-leaver ng-star-inserted", Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'image-tile__content-header') and contains(text(),'End Date, Contract') and contains(@class, 'image-tile__badge')]")).GetAttribute("Class"));

Assert.Equal("image-tile__badge background-color--status-leaver ng-star-inserted", Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'image-tile__content-header') and contains(text(),'End Date, Contract')]")).FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'image-tile__badge')]")).GetAttribute("Class"));
```

The last one finds the element when the status is 'new', but when i change the employee status to 'leaver', it still returns as 'new' so possibly looking at another employee with a 'new' status.

Hopefully this is enough info, let me know if more is needed (this is my first ever post!)
HTML code in image below

[HTML code on Chrome]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUxkf.png

Summary: im trying to assert that the Employee "End Date, Contract" has the status of leaver (aka the leaver class "image-tile__badge background-color--status-leaver ng-star-inserted")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their help!
One of my devs managed to take @noldors example and modify it a bit so heres what ended up working for me:

```
 var newElmList1 = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.background-color--status-leaver")).ToList();
            List<string> newNames1 = new List<string>();
            foreach (var newElm in newElmList1)
            {
                var newName1 = newElm.FindElement(By.XPath(".."))
                                    .FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.image-tile__content-header")).Text;
                newNames.Add(newName1);
            }
            if (!newNames.Contains("End Date, Contract"))
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception Error on leaver Person");
            }
```

Comment: Hey reb, you can mark your own answer as "The Answer" :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you can find all elements with 'Leaver' specific class with this;

```
 var leaverElmList = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.background-color--status-leaver")).ToList();
 List<string> leaverNames = new List<string>();
 foreach (var leaverElm in leaverElmList) {
    var leaverName = leaverElm.FindElement(By.XPath(".."))
                        .FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.image-tile__content-header"));
                        .Text()
    leaverNames.Add(leaverName);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! im trying to assert that the Employee "End Date, Contract" (thats his name in the test) has the status of leaver. I assume your advice allows me to find out  how many leavers exist, but i need to assert that particular employee is leaver

Comment: @RebekkahHunter updated the code in my answer.. check it out.

Comment: Thanks again! i appreciate all your help but getting the count of leavers will not work as this number may change in my test environment. I need to assert.equal that the Element that contains text "End Date, Contract" has the class of "image-tile__badge background-color--status-leaver ng-star-inserted". Maybe its just not possible with the structure of the HTML?

Comment: @RebekkahHunter this doesn't give you count.. it first finds all leavers with "background-color--status-leaver" then goes to their parent for each leaver and finds "End Date, Contract" element's text.. you said in your previous comment that it was the name of the leaver, I thought you wanted to find the names of leavers?? In the end you have a list with names of the leaver in "leaverNames" list object.

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot i fill it's better if you try using Xpath

```
var elmList = Driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[contains(text(),'leaver')]")).ToList();
```

i hope it will help you
Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for your reply also! But again, im trying to assert that the Employee "End Date, Contract" (thats his name in the test) has the status of leaver.

Getting the count of leavers will not work as this number may change in my test environment. I need to **assert.equal** that the Element that contains text _"End Date, Contract"_ has the class of _"image-tile__badge background-color--status-leaver ng-star-inserted"_. Maybe its just not possible with the structure of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Enddate, Contract which is not related to the div that contains Leaver. It's direct parent is the image-tile div